# An unhandled exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll

Tags: c#

I'm trying to code a tinychat bot that connects to the chatroom.

This is my code for the connection.

```
private void _buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] TCargs = new string[] { _textBoxApplication.Text, "none", "show", "tinychat" };

    // Connect to the server.
    string url = "rtmp://" + _textBoxServer.Text + ":" + System.Convert.ToInt32(_textBoxPort.Text) + "/" + "tinyconf";

    _netConnection.Connect("rtmp://" + _textBoxServer + ":" + _textBoxPort.Text + "/" + "tinyconf" + TCargs);
    //_netConnection.Connect(url, "user", "password");
}
```

I'm getting this error when I hit the connect button:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll

and it doesn't connect or anything.

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: Is there anyway I can add you on skype and you help me out with this, I'm a noob with this, I've went from no code to this much tho so I suppose you can say I'm learning.

Comment: You are concatenating strings and objects and arrays in the `_netConnection.Connect(...)`. The result of that will likely be something like "rtmp://System.Windows.Forms.TextBox:1234/tinyconfSystem.String[]".

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, I'm using FluorineFx and I did it like the example shows but it's not connecting.

Is this what you mean?
m_connection.Connect("rtmp://209.212.144.108:1936/tinyconf", strArray);

Comment: And this is the exception : Additional information: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

It's because I left the .Text off of serverbox so I added that and still no connection.